# How to use gradient descent for cosine similarity optimization?

Tags: python, tensorflow, optimization, vector, gradient-descent

so I have a vector A with 1508 dimensions that is defined, I have another list of n vectors in a list called C. Each of the n vectors is attributed a weight, and a vector B is defined by the following for each dimension : The weight times the first dimension of it's vector + the second weight times the first dimension of it's vector etc.... and all that divided by the sum of the weights. Basically I want to find the best combination of the n vectors to form a goal vector A. But the combination is done by averaging the dimensions of the vectors. Also the weights can only take 1 or 0 as a value. I tried to use Tensorflow's gradient descent in the following way :

```
import tensorflow as tf
tf.compat.v1.disable_eager_execution()

# Define the dimensions of the vectors
d = 1508
import numpy as np
import random
import math
# Define the variables
A = [random.uniform(0, 1) for _ in range(d)]
C = [[random.uniform(0, 1) for k in range(d)] for _ in range(4)]
a0 = a1 = a2 = a3 = 1
variables = [a0,a1,a2,a3]

# Define B as a linear combination of the vectors in C
B = []
for l in range(d):
    value = 0
    for i in range(4):
        value = value + variables[i] * C[i][l]
    B.append(value/sum(variables))

# Use a sigmoid activation to squash the variables to the range [0, 1]
variables = [1 / (1 + math.exp(-v)) for v in variables]


# Round the variables to 0 or 1
variables = [tf.round(v) for v in variables]
variables = [tf.Variable(v) for v in variables]



def loss(A,B):

    return 1 - tf.keras.losses.cosine_similarity(A, B)
    # Define the loss function


# Use an optimizer to minimize the loss
optimizer = tf.keras.optimizers.SGD(learning_rate=0.01)


num_steps = 100
import sys
# Run the training loop
for _ in range(num_steps):
  with tf.GradientTape() as tape:
    B = []
    for l in range(d):
      value = 0
      for i in range(4):
          value = value + variables[i] * C[i][l]
      B.append(value/sum(variables))
    loss_value = loss(A, B)
    grads = tape.gradient(loss_value, variables)
    
  print(loss_value)
  print(grads)
  print(len(grads))
  optimizer.apply_gradients(zip(grads, variables)) 
  variables = [tf.clip_by_value(v, 0, 1) for v in variables]
  variables = [tf.Variable(v) for v in variables]
```

In this example I used 4 weights. But for some reason I can ever get the value of the variables to be printed out and I have no clue if this is working.

That's what I've tried, I was wondering if anyone had ideas on finding best combination of vectors to reach goal vector and what they used. Also will gradient descent work for this? Also I can't get the values from the variables, .numpy doesn't work tf. print doesn't work etc... Thanks! Here is what I get from running it for a bit :

```
[<tf.Tensor 'AddN_1:0' shape=() dtype=float32>, <tf.Tensor 'AddN_2:0' shape=() dtype=float32>, <tf.Tensor 'AddN_3:0' shape=() dtype=float32>, <tf.Tensor 'AddN_4:0' shape=() dtype=float32>]
4
[<tf.Tensor 'AddN_6:0' shape=() dtype=float32>, <tf.Tensor 'AddN_7:0' shape=() dtype=float32>, <tf.Tensor 'AddN_8:0' shape=() dtype=float32>, <tf.Tensor 'AddN_9:0' shape=() dtype=float32>]
4
[<tf.Tensor 'AddN_11:0' shape=() dtype=float32>, <tf.Tensor 'AddN_12:0' shape=() dtype=float32>, <tf.Tensor 'AddN_13:0' shape=() dtype=float32>, <tf.Tensor 'AddN_14:0' shape=() dtype=float32>]
4
[<tf.Tensor 'AddN_16:0' shape=() dtype=float32>, <tf.Tensor 'AddN_17:0' shape=() dtype=float32>, <tf.Tensor 'AddN_18:0' shape=() dtype=float32>, <tf.Tensor 'AddN_19:0' shape=() dtype=float32>]
4
[<tf.Tensor 'AddN_21:0' shape=() dtype=float32>, <tf.Tensor 'AddN_22:0' shape=() dtype=float32>, <tf.Tensor 'AddN_23:0' shape=() dtype=float32>, <tf.Tensor 'AddN_24:0' shape=() dtype=float32>]
4
[<tf.Tensor 'AddN_26:0' shape=() dtype=float32>, <tf.Tensor 'AddN_27:0' shape=() dtype=float32>, <tf.Tensor 'AddN_28:0' shape=() dtype=float32>, <tf.Tensor 'AddN_29:0' shape=() dtype=float32>]
4
[<tf.Tensor 'AddN_31:0' shape=() dtype=float32>, <tf.Tensor 'AddN_32:0' shape=() dtype=float32>, <tf.Tensor 'AddN_33:0' shape=() dtype=float32>, <tf.Tensor 'AddN_34:0' shape=() dtype=float32>]
4
[<tf.Tensor 'AddN_36:0' shape=() dtype=float32>, <tf.Tensor 'AddN_37:0' shape=() dtype=float32>, <tf.Tensor 'AddN_38:0' shape=() dtype=float32>, <tf.Tensor 'AddN_39:0' shape=() dtype=float32>]
4
[<tf.Tensor 'AddN_41:0' shape=() dtype=float32>, <tf.Tensor 'AddN_42:0' shape=() dtype=float32>, <tf.Tensor 'AddN_43:0' shape=() dtype=float32>, <tf.Tensor 'AddN_44:0' shape=() dtype=float32>]
4
```

Thanks for the help!!!!

Comment: Why do you disable eager execution but then write code that only works for eager execution?

Comment: Oh I forgot to remove that, it was because I had some other issue and tried to disable eager execution.

Comment: Please have a look at this [gist](https://colab.research.google.com/gist/RenuPatelGoogle/03c6486c99c1d39f1376642434f9e0fe/74985816.ipynb). Is this the same output you are looking for?